# How do I style alternating WordPress posts?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have some posts displaying from a specific category but need them to have a little different styling on every second post.

This code I have displays all posts in a list with the same styling.

How do I edit this code and make it so I can edit the styling of ***ONLY*** every second post?

As it stands there's text on the left and an image on the right - the second posts just need to switch sides - it's simple styling but I'm unsure how to break the posts up to edit `#case-left` & `#case-right` are the two divs that need to switch.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php // PAGE LINK/TITLE          
if (is_page()) {
    $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
    $posts = get_posts ("category_name=case-study&posts_per_page=10");

    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post); 

?>

    <div class="serve-inner-split"> 
        <div id="case-split">
            <div id="case-left" class=" serve-left">
                <div id="case-study-content">
                    <h1 class="case-study-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <p><?php //PULLS IN EXCERPT
                        $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                        if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                        // Some string manipulation performed
                        }
                        echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page
                    ?>
                    </p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="header-quote">READ CASE STUDY</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="case-right" class="serve-grey">
                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // PULLS IN IMAGE check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } 
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php endforeach;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: You can add a counter in the php that will add a specific class on every 2nd post, or you can target every second post with `:nth-of-type(2n)` selector.

Comment: Also, PHP is of little use here, the output HTML would be prefereable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php // PAGE LINK/TITLE          
if (is_page()) {
  $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
  $posts = get_posts ("category_name=case-study&posts_per_page=10");
  if ($posts) {
    $counter = 1;
    $class = '';
    foreach ($posts as $post):
      setup_postdata($post); 
       if($counter%2 == 0) {
          $class = "even-no";
       } else {
        $class = '';
       }

?>
<div class="serve-inner-split <?php echo $class; ?>"> 
                <div id="case-split">
                        <div id="case-left" class=" serve-left">
                            <div id="case-study-content">
                                <h1 class="case-study-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                                <p><?php //PULLS IN EXCERPT
                                    $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                                    if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                                        // Some string manipulation performed
                                    }
                                    echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page

                                    ?>
                                </p>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="header-quote">READ CASE STUDY</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="case-right" class="serve-grey">
   <?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // PULLS IN IMAGE check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>


<?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endforeach;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hope it wiil help you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so when editing your question I saw that you want to style it so that the divs switch places. You can do that like this in php

```
<?php // PAGE LINK/TITLE
if (is_page()){}
    $i = 0;
    $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
    $posts = get_posts ("category_name=case-study&posts_per_page=10");
    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 == 0):?>
        <div class="serve-inner-split">
            <div id="case-split">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
                <div id="case-right" class="serve-grey">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div id="case-left" class=" serve-left">
                    <div id="case-study-content">
                        <h1 class="case-study-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <p><?php //PULLS IN EXCERPT
                            $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                            if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                                // Some string manipulation performed
                            }
                            echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page

                            ?>
                        </p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="header-quote">READ CASE STUDY</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="serve-inner-split">
            <div id="case-split">
                <div id="case-left" class=" serve-left">
                    <div id="case-study-content">
                        <h1 class="case-study-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <p><?php //PULLS IN EXCERPT
                            $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                            if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                                // Some string manipulation performed
                            }
                            echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page

                            ?>
                        </p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="header-quote">READ CASE STUDY</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
                <div id="case-right" class="serve-grey">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;
?>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

But in my opinion, that's kinda unnecessary. You can also do it like this:

```
<?php // PAGE LINK/TITLE
if (is_page()){}
    $i = 0;
    $cat=get_cat_ID($post->post_title); //use page title to get a category ID
    $posts = get_posts ("category_name=case-study&posts_per_page=10");
    if ($posts) {
        foreach ($posts as $post):
        setup_postdata($post);
    $class = '';
    $i++;
    if ($i % 2 == 0){
        $class = 'right_image'
    }
?>
        <div class="serve-inner-split <?php echo $class; ?>">
            <div id="case-split">
                <div id="case-left" class=" serve-left">
                    <div id="case-study-content">
                        <h1 class="case-study-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                        <p><?php //PULLS IN EXCERPT
                            $my_excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                            if ( '' != $my_excerpt ) {
                                // Some string manipulation performed
                            }
                            echo $my_excerpt; // Outputs the processed value to the page

                            ?>
                        </p>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="header-quote">READ CASE STUDY</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ):?>
                <div id="case-right" class="serve-grey">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
} ?>
```

And then float the image the other way (or use absolute positioning or whatever suits you), with the '.right_image' class in the css.

Comment: Ok, so what's wrong with my answer? The code works and it explains what you get... Jeez, some people will do anything to get their answer accepted.